# Waiting for an external response without consuming resources

Tags: python, python-asyncio, pickle, external

I have a simple python program that needs to apply a function to circles based on their radius. My issue is, I need to fetch the radius from a third-party API, which may take up to several hours to send me the radius sizes, as a csv file for instance.

To be clearer:

```py
class Circle():
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        self.radius = None

def fetch_radius(circle):
    ''' call an API and retrieve radius based on 
        the circle id.
    '''
    radius = fetch_from_api(circle.id) # takes hour to return
    circle.radius = radius

def main():
    circle = Circle(id=2)
    fetch_radius(circle.id)
```

This design seems flawed, because my program and objects hang for hours waiting for an external signal, and consume resources.

How can I improve my design ?

Edit : I thought of pickling the object and closing the program waiting for the answer, but I'm not convinced. Yehven also talked about asyncio. I add both keywords.

Comment: Look into [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html)

Comment: I'll have a look! I didn't think of it because I need that radius data to perform the becoming operations, but maybe I'm missing something about that library's capacities.

Comment: What resources are you concerned about? You have a running application that is keeping a connection open. Some amount of memory and CPU are going to be used. Something like asyncio won’t prevent that. It would just allow you to do other things while you’re waiting for the API to respond.

Comment: Well, in fact, once the request is sent, I receive a csv file on a ftp 5 hours after. I guess I could event shut down my program while I have not received my file ? And yes, in that case, asyncio won't help